# Can one know what he was in his previous life?

Tags: karma, rebirth, life

Is it possible to know what a person was in his previous life.
Male, female , person's likes and dislikes, his interests and what was his good and bad karma??

Comment: Yes. It is possible. Swami Vivekananda said he was able to. And he gives the method to recall it - for 12 years, practice satya, brahmacharya and aparigraha, continuously without break. Patanjali Yoga sutras also mention to practice samayama on memories. Now it's totally up to you whether you want to test this hypothesis yourself or call it fake.

Comment: @ram you are absolutely correct.I think this topic was discussed here and quotes from scriptures was provided supporting your view in an answer.

Comment: @ram "Now it's totally up to you whether you want to test this hypothesis yourself or call it fake." well it should be easy enough to fake. "Swami Vivekananda said he was able to" how do you know he was telling the truth?

Comment: @Wikash_hindu, how do you know scientists were telling the truth when they said 'black holes exist' 100 years ago ? It took a hundred years of experiments to finally show an image, right ? same way.. if u r willing to do a 100 years of penance, you can see your past lives.

Comment: Ajna chakra associated with Pineal gland has all your previous life memories. Pitutary gland has future visions. When these chakras open up due to raise of PRANAN (Pranan is different from Prana) you can get to know everything and at the awakening of Sahasra chakra, you'll get direct perception of Brahman. At this stage, even if you have not read Vedas, all Vedic knowledge flows in you here!!!!

Comment: @ram " if u r willing to do a 100 years of penance, you can see your past lives." Prove this then I'll do it.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu, it is already proven by Swami Vivekananda.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu, you repeating the same argument without understanding. you only need to trust the process, you don't need to trust the rishis. Like when a scientist says "if you study physics, you can prove existence of electromagnetic waves", and you ask "first prove it, then i'll do it", and scientist says "look, you don't need to believe me that EM waves exist. But you need to trust that my process for proving EM works, and if you follow that process, you can verify for yourself that EM waves exist". Same way, rishis say "If u do penance for 12 years, you can see past lives".

Comment: @ram No the scientist WILL prove it to me since he can fall back on basic laws of nature. From that on he can show the building blocks for the proof. You however rely on belief but belief can lead to truth and untruth making it an unreliable method for finding the truth.

Comment: "it is already proven by Swami Vivekananda." It is just a story I do need see any proof.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu, scientists doesn't show you the proof, he only shows you the process to get to the proof. scientists rely on belief in the process. i don't rely on any belief. it is a very reliable way to find out truth, just need to follow the process for 12 years, and we'll verify if it is true or not. it's just like going to store and buying a mango and eating it. without doing those basic work, you can never prove anything. No, Vivekananda has given scientific proof of it. you just don't know about it.

Comment: @ram "scientists rely on belief in the process" no they do not they build via facts upon facts and build the proof bottom-up which is an excellent type of proof.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu, nope, they rely on belief in the process. if a scientist says "X exists", and a person asks for proof, they'll say "if you follow steps 1, 2, 3, you can see X", and the person replies "I won't do steps 1,2,3", then they'll say "you need not trust us that X exists. but you need to trust us that if you do steps 1,2,3, you can prove for yourself that X exists. but if you don't even trust the steps, then we can't do anything to prove it"

Comment: @ram no you are wrong. They use basic natural laws and build the proof upon that. That's the beauty of it: by building fact upon fact one can draw conclusions. In your case I need to have some belief and I already told you that belief can lead to truth and untruth.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu, no you are wrong. rishis use basic natural laws and build the proof upon it. That's the beauty of it: by building fact upon fact one can draw conclusions. you need to have atleast a basic understanding of maths before you can ask for proof of fermat's last theorem. if a mathematician says, study for 20 years and the proof will be evident, but you say 'i first need to know what is 2+2 and you need to prove that to me', it just shows you are not aware of the basic truths. similarly, you are not aware of the basic laws upon which rishis build more complex proofs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92959/discussion-between-ram-and-wikash-hindu).